# How to get the value of a check box in ApplescriptObjC

Tags: xcode, checkbox, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm trying to get the value of a check box in ApplescriptObjC.

```
    on goClicked_(sender)

        set checkBoxValue to checkBox's stringValue as boolean

    end goClicked_
```

This code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Say more about your context. Is this a handler in an ASObjC app in Xcode, and the checkbox is in the window you've built in IB? If so, you will/should have setup either an outlet or a property binding.

Comment: I have the outlets and such. I also have everything hooked up. I'm now just trying to get the value of the checkbox I put on my UI. Like true or false or 1 or 0.

Comment: Trying your code with outlets set correctly Xcode gives me `-[AppDelegate goClicked:]: Can’t make stringValue of ... id ... into type boolean.` without the _as boolean_ it answers 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If checkBox is set as an outlet, then you can get its state [0/1] with:

```
set checkBoxValue to (checkBox's state())
```